# SQL - format INT to date and add condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, datetime

I have a table with a date column. This column is an INT and contains dates in the format YYYYMMDD (for example 20160713). Now I want to get all rows where these dates are after today. I tried the following:

```
SELECT ID, startdate, comment
FROM comments
WHERE startdate > getdate
```

But that results in to following error:

> Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type datetime.

So I tried it by formatting it to a dd/mm/yyyy format

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), (convert(date,CONVERT(varchar(10),[startdate],103))),103) > getdate()
```

but that results into this error:

> The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

Any ideas how to do this?

Comment: Read Aaron Bertrand's [Bad habits to kick : choosing the wrong data type](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try following query

```
SELECT 
    ID, 
    startdate, 
    comment
FROM 
    comments
WHERE 
    stadate > CAST(CONVERT(varchar(8),getdate(),112) AS INT)
```

Comment: I just wonder that if i have 1000 rows then getdate() will converted 1000 times or just one time? If more Its better that using a variable, converted

Comment: This difference will be extremely minor in practice with just 1000 rows. I think you'd start noticing significant differences if the query was run a LOT of times or if it was over millions of rows, though, but mostly due to the repeated casts/converts.

Answer (score 2):

You could try to cast your int to a date value, but that means that the query would not be able to use any indexes that you might have on your `startdate` column.
The other option is to convert the date returned from the `GETDATE()` to an int value that matches your int format:

```
DECLARE @Now datetime = GETDATE();
DECLARE @NowInt int =  YEAR(@Now) * 10000 + MONTH(@Now) * 100 + DAY(@Now);

SELECT ID, startdate, comment
FROM comments
WHERE startdate > @NowInt;
```

This way the `GetDate()` is executed only once, the conversion to int is also executed only once, and your query can use an index on `startdate` if you have one.

Answer (score 1):

it's more easy to convert `getDate` to `int`.

```
cast(format(getDate(),'yyyyMMdd') as int)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT ID, startdate, comment
FROM comments
WHERE CAST(startdate AS DATE) > getdate()
```

Comment: If startdate really is an int, it will not cast to date, but should properly be something like `CAST(CAST(startdate AS VARCHAR(8))) AS DATE)`

Comment: `As a number in either YYYYMMDD or YYMMDD format, provided that the number makes sense as a date. For example, 19830905 and 830905 are interpreted as '1983-09-05'.` [**REFERENCE**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/datetime.html). @AllanS.Hansen

Comment: tag is sql server, not mysql

Comment: Initially there was `MySQL` tag. Check all the [**revisions**](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/38344194/revisions) please.

Comment: That doesn't change it wouldn't work for sql server which was also a tag (and still is) and answer wasn't specified for _only_ mysql

Comment: I got your point @AllanS.Hansen. By the way, it's not my answer :p. Though the names are almost similar.

Comment: LOL. must be a earlier version of you

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ID, startdate, comment
FROM comments
WHERE CAST(STR(startdate) AS DATE) > getdate()
```

Comment: don't apply function on the column. It will give bad performance

Answer (score 0):

don't convert the column, but convert the getdate() to integer

```
SELECT ID, startdate, comment
FROM comments
WHERE startdate > CONVERT(INT, CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), getdate, 112))
```

I guess others must have commented on using wrong data type for dates ..... so i will not mention anything on that :)